# Shrink a cell (in an absolutely-positioned ASP.NET table) to fit its contents?

Tags: asp.net, width, cell

**My webpage currently looks like this:**

```
<asp:Table runat="server" style="position: absolute;
    left: 0%; top: 82%; right: 0%; bottom: 0%; width: 100%; height: 18%"
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="Both">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Content1
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell Width="2.5%">
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell >
            Content2
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/9677/tableu.png

**But I need it to look like this:**
http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/4508/table2k.png
"Content1" is of unknown size, and the table will have to adjust to fit it in, but without taking any unnecessary space away from "Content2." I can't use "display: table" because it isn't supported in IE7 and such, so I'm pretty much stuck using a regular table element unless there is something better out there that is supported in older browsers.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a width to the Content2 cell?  Something like:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" style="position: absolute;
    left: 0%; top: 82%; right: 0%; bottom: 0%; width: 100%; height: 18%"
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="Both">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Content1
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell Width="2.5%">
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell Width="97.5%">
            Content2
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```